# how to take foreach result in a table format

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to take the result of foreach in a table format and that whole table in a variable.
Here is my model:

```
        public function cron_job_seller(){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('wc_seller_products');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = array();
        foreach ($query->result() as $row){
            $result[] = $row;
         }
         return $result; 
      }
```

and my controller is

```
public function cron_job(){
$this->load->model('home/Home_model');
$buyer = $this->Home_model->cron_job_buyer();
$this->load->library('email', array('mailtype'=>'html'));
$seller = $this->Home_model->cron_job_seller();


echo "<table>";
foreach($seller as $key=>$row) {
echo "<tr>";
foreach($row as $key2=>$row2){
    echo "<td>" . $row2 . "</td>"; 
}
echo "</tr>";
}
 echo "</table>";
```

gives o/p like this in table format

```
 19 102 Rolex   65  Good    0000-00-00  fh  ghf fgh ghf ghf gfh ghf ghf 56  56  download14.jpg  11/6/2016 19:03 2016-07-15 12:13:35 1   0
```

when i print $seller variable it gives

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 19 [seller_id] => 102 [brand_name] => Rolex [model_no] => 65 [condition] => Good [date_purchase] => 0000-00-00 [case_size] => fh [case_shape] => ghf [case_material] => fgh [strap_type] => ghf [dial_colour] => ghf [water_resistance] => gfh [local_overseas] => ghf [warranty_period] => ghf [min_price] => 56 [sale_price] => 56 [photo] => download14.jpg [date] => 11/6/2016 19:03 [time] => 2016-07-15 12:13:35 [status] => 1 [login] => 0 [verified] => )
```

now i want 2 things in this:
1. that whole table in a single variable.
2. array keys like id, seller_id,brand_name as table heading

i really got confused what to do now and how to do...please help

Comment: Did you try to give border etc. to table,  `echo "<table>";` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
public function cron_job() {
    $this->load->model('home/Home_model');
    $buyer = $this->Home_model->cron_job_buyer();
    $this->load->library('email', array('mailtype'=>'html'));
    $seller = $this->Home_model->cron_job_seller();

    $theader = '';
    $tbody = "<tbody>";
    foreach($seller as $key => $row) {
        $tbody .= "<tr>";
        foreach($row as $key2 => $row2){
            if (!$theader) {
                $theader = array_keys($row2);
            }
            $tbody .= "<td>" . $row2 . "</td>"; 
        }
        $tbody .=  "</tr>";
    }

    $tbody .= "</tbody>";
    if (!empty($theader)) {
        $theader = '<thead><th>' . implode('</th><th>', $theader) . '</th></thead>';
    }
    $table = '<table>'.$theader.$tbody.'</table>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to worry much about it... It could be a solution. Just do like this in your controller:

```
$seller = $this->Home_model->cron_job_seller();
$table = "<table border='1'>";
$i=1;
foreach($seller as $key=>$row) { //you don't need to loop twice
     if($i == 1){
         $table.="<tr>";
         $table .= "<th>".$key."</th>";
         $table.="</tr>";
         $i=0; //change value of $i so for next iteration the header will not print
       }
     $table .= "<tr>";
     $table .= "<td>" . $row . "</td>"; 
     $table.= "</tr>";
}
$table .= "</table>";
```

and also you need to return `$query->result()` from your model.
and now try print `$table`
using `echo $table;` it will print result as you want and now it is also set in a single variable so you can, and you set to `$data['table'] = $table` and end it to view, if you need.

Comment: thank you!! but what if i also want table heading like id,seller_id,brand_name as shown above

Comment: return `$query->result();` from model, you don't need to loop there

Answer (score 0):

You are doing correct but need some modifications
What you need to do is in you second foreach() loop you need to convert your object to array and take out the array keys `array_keys($array)` in a variable and print this keys to variable. As shown bellow.

```
$table = "<table border='1'>";
foreach($seller as $key=>$row) { //you don't need to loop twice
    $table .="<tr>";
    // creating a table heading 
    if($key === 0 ){
        $cols = array_keys((array)$row); // Convert the object to array and take out all keys of array and assign to $cols variable
        $table .="<th>".implode("</th><th>", $cols); 
        $table .="</th></tr><tr>";
    }
    // table heading end

    $table .= '<td>'. implode('</td><td>', (array)$row). '</td>';
    $table .= "</tr>";
}
$table .="</table>";
echo $table;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just loop through the Array of Data from the DB and since each row is an array of Standard PHP Object (which contains the column names as keys), you can then extract the Column Names from the first row and then use it to construct the Table Header. Afterwards, you can just continue building Rows containing the actual Data you want. The Code below illustrates how:

```
    <?php

        function cron_job() {
            $strOutput = "<table class='cron-tbl'>";
            $this->load->model('home/Home_model');
            $buyer      = $this->Home_model->cron_job_buyer();
            $this->load->library('email', array('mailtype' => 'html'));
            $seller     = $this->Home_model->cron_job_seller();

            $cue        = 0;
            foreach ($seller as $key => $row) {
                if($cue == 0){
                    // CREATE THE HEADER ROW:
                    $strOutput .= "<tr class='cron-head-row'>" . PHP_EOL;
                    foreach($row as $rowName=>$rowVal){
                        $strOutput .= "<th class='cron-head-cell'>{$rowName}</th>" . PHP_EOL;
                    }
                    $strOutput .= "</tr>" . PHP_EOL;
                    $strOutput .= "<tbody class='cron-body'>" . PHP_EOL;
                }

                // CREATE THE TABLE-BODY CELL
                  $strOutput .= "</tr>" . PHP_EOL;
                foreach ($row as $rowKey => $data) {
                    $strOutput .= "<td class='cron-data-cell'>{$data}</td>" . PHP_EOL;
                }
                $strOutput .= "</tr>" . PHP_EOL;
                $cue++;
            }
            $strOutput .= "</tbody>"  . PHP_EOL;
            $strOutput .=  "</table>" . PHP_EOL;;

            return $strOutput;
        }

        echo (cron_job());
```

Cheers & Good Luck...

Test it out yourself [HERE](https://eval.in/606755).

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.
I guess html tag, body tag are missing. That's why didnot display table the way you want. 
My suggestion is that for html part, it is better if put in view. 
I have create view page `cron_job_seller.php` with bootstrap.

```
// Model - Change to this
public function cron_job_seller() 
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('wc_seller_products');

    return $this->db->get();    
}

// Controller
public function cron_job() {

    $this->load->model('home/Home_model');
    $this->load->library('email', array('mailtype'=>'html'));

    $buyer = $this->Home_model->cron_job_buyer();
    $seller = $this->Home_model->cron_job_seller();

    $data['seller'] = $seller // Send data to View

    // Create cron_job_seller.php file in Views Folder.
    $this->load->view('cron_job_seller', $data); 
}

// View cron_job_seller.php 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Sample Table</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <?php foreach($seller->result() as $row) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row->colname_1; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->colname_2; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->colname_3; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->colname_4; ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </table>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```